# Does slow down in read/write from RAID 1 in a SAS array cause it to be slower than RAID5 SATA?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

And which is faster?

(450GB)x2 SAS configured for RAID 1 (mirroring) with 15k RPM, 16MB cache
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148559

or

(300GB)x3 SATA configured for RAID 5 (striping with parity) with 10k RPM, 16MB cache
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136802

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit too simplistic. The answer depends on the mix of reads and writes and other factors.

I would be disappointed if 15k RAID-1 SAS didn't outperform 10k RAID-5 SATA. Your Mileage May Vary.